# INSERT INTO, if already exist UPDATE. from an existing query. to be put on SQL Agent job

Tags: sql-server

I will try to be clear.

I have a query to pull data :

```
select typ_no_store as IDstore, str_name as 'name', (CASE WHEN str_addr2 IS NULL THEN str_addr1 ELSE str_addr2 END) as adresse, str_postal as postalcode 
    from store_type inner join STRFIL on typ_no_store = str_store_no
    where typ_code = 'a'
```

That will result in something like this :

```
001 Newy store          600 BLVD someht                 G11111    
002 LA store            770 BLVD ests                   G22222    
010 Texas store         112 dsntexists                  G33333
```

I need to put the ongoing changes of this result into a new table. 
I've created a table name 'Webstore' with the same column value. (IDstore,name,adresse,postalcode)

I need a query that will INSERT INTO or UPDATE(if ID already exist) the result of the query into the new table. The query will run every 2 hours on SQL server Agent.

I tried command like IF EXIST, ON DUPLICATE KEY and MERGE but I can't get it to work. It seems that because I must pull the data from a query and not from typed values or an entire Table it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

(Sorry if my english is not clear, don't hesitate to ask question Thank you !!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MERGE in sql server.

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
  SELECT typ_no_store as IDstore, 
    str_name as 'name', 
    (CASE WHEN str_addr2 IS NULL THEN str_addr1 ELSE str_addr2 END) as adresse, 
    str_postal as postalcode
  FROM store_type
  INNER JOIN STRFIL on typ_no_store = str_store_no
  WHERE typ_code = 'a'
)

MERGE Webstore AS t
USING cte AS s
ON t.IDstore=s.IDstore
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET t.[name]=s.name,
      t.other fields = s.other fields ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (IDstore, other fields...)
  VALUES(s.IDstore, s.other fields)
;
```

Comment: `WITH` doesn't  start with a `;`l it's your previous statement that should have been correctly terminated. `;` isn't a "beginninator" it's a terminator.

Comment: WITH requires the previous statement ended with ;. So it is good to add ; before WITH in case the previous statement not ended with ;

Comment: Working like a charm !! thank you very much for the fast respond my good sir !

Comment: That actually teaches bad habits, as people then start to think that `;` is a "beginningator" for `WITH` and `MERGE`, when it isn't. With is why you end you seeing syntax like `;WITH CTE1 AS( ...); CTE 2 AS (...) ;MERGE...` and people wondering why it doesn't work. If the OP is getting that error it's because they haven't properly terminated their statements, and should be putting the `;` at the end of the statement.